# Два параметра с одним именем, но разных типов [Delphi, X-SuperObject, JSON]

Tags: delphi, json

Имеем что-то типа:

```
{
  "xxfile.txt": 666,
  "xxfile.txt": {

  },
  "123": {
    "dir1": {
      "file.txt": 123
    }
  },
  "dir0": {
    "dir2": {
      "file2.txt": 321,
      "dir3": {
        "filex.txt": 777
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Возможно ли как-то обратиться именно к объекту или именно к числовому значению по имени "xxfile.txt"? Или это не предусмотрено? Интересует средствами XSuperObject (Delphi). Что-то застрял. Пытался обратиться как к объекту но вылетает исключение что тип не тот (видать обращается к первому числовому).

Баг XSuperObject или ограничения самого JSON?

PS: если есть возможность обратиться из XSuperObject и как к объекту и как к числу, но у меня руки из неправильного места, то прошу кусочек кода.

Comment: Всяким "доброжелателям" с высоким рангом просьба не редактировать мой вопрос!!! Я задал вопрос и хочу его видеть именно таким! Здесь я выразил что мне нужно, а не то что хотят видеть "доброжелатели".

Comment: ваше _"что-то типа"_ называется невалидный json

Comment: @teran, значит всё-же в JSON не может быть двух одинаковых параметров разного типа? Мне бы хоть это узнать. Если это так, то знаю как поправить свой код.

Comment: формально, [стандартом наличие повторных ключей прямо не запрещено](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#section-4). Однако на практике мало какие парсеры будут с подобным работать корректно. Так что тут не ограничение JSON и  не баг СО, а скорее ограничение СО.

Comment: @teran, понял, лучше уж буду помечать "директорию" слешем, чтобы не было косяков в будущем

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для JSON формата есть спецификация [RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159), согласно которой ([секция 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-4)), определено, что имена в пределах объекта **должны быть уникальны**:

> The names within an object SHOULD be unique.

Там так же указано, что в случае, если это не так, и есть дублирование имён, то поведение не определено и зависит от реализации парсера. Некоторые парсеры возвращают значения первой или последней пары имя/значение, другие сообщают об ошибке и прекращают парсинг, третьи возвращают все пары имя/значение, включая дубликаты.

`XSuperObject` относится к тому типу парсеров, которые возвращают только одно из значений, в случае обнаружения дубликатов. Кстати, похоже, что так было не всегда и какие-то старые версии могли возвращать все дубликаты (см. тикет на гитхабе: [Only The Last Duplicate Pair Is Accessable In A ISuperObject Containing Duplicate Name/Value Pairs](https://github.com/onryldz/x-superobject/issues/37)), но потом это поведение было изменено.

C другой стороны, используя встроенный в Delphi парсер JSON можно дотянуться до дубликатов:

```
uses
  System.JSON;

procedure DoTest;
var
  I: Integer;
  VJson: string;
  VJsonPair: TJSONPair;
  VJsonObject: TJSONObject;
begin
  VJson := '{"name":"bob", "name":"joe"}';
  VJsonObject := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(VJson) as TJSONObject;
  if VJsonObject <> nil then begin
    try
      for I := 0 to VJsonObject.Count - 1 do begin
        VJsonPair := VJsonObject.Pairs[I];
        Writeln(VJsonPair.ToString);
      end;
    finally
      VJsonObject.Free;
    end;
  end else begin
    // ToDo: handle json parser error
  end;
end;
```

Выведет 2 строки:

```
"name":"bob"
"name":"joe"
```

Но и тут, я думаю нету 100% гарантии, что в будущем это поведение не изменится.

Comment: перевод "должны"  тут не совсем корректен. все таки _должны_ это _must_,

Comment: @teran Не согласен. Если при несоблюдении условия мы сталкиваемся с неопределённым поведением, то условие следует рассматривать как строгое.

Comment: Понял. Значит буду просто помечать "директорию" слешем вначале =)